# Wordpress post sitting ontop of div, not inside

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm not sure why this is, but my wordpress post isn't actually nested inside the div that the PHP code is nested in.

Here is the code on the html side:

```
<!-- BLOG -->
<div class="blog" id="blog">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php 
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
            $postslist = get_posts( $args );
            echo '<section id="latest_posts">';
            foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
            <h2><?php the_date(); ?></h2>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <p><?php the_content();?></p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the only CSS affecting this code:

```
/* BLOG */
.blog {
    background-image: url("../images/pat_1_bg.png");
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Any idea why this would be sitting outside of the div? It's almost like it has a positive z-index, which it doesn't. I can change the height of 'blog' as much as I want, and it will indeed affect the height of the div, but the post content is unaffected.

Comment: I actually came to realize that the post is sitting inside the body of the page, but ignoring div. Is there some info someone may share with me on why this is? Should I maybe change the parent div to a section instead?

Comment: can you please share a screenshot of how it is looking now and how you want it to look..

Comment: if you have float:left; or float:right for any div, you should set overflow:hidden to the parent of that div. Please check if my comment helps

Comment: Are you trying to display this code as normal page template or as a short-code?

Comment: When doing a loop, try storing all the data in a variable (for ex. `$out`) and then just return that variable inside the container where you want it. Cleaner code imo.